# How to convert document Illustrator file to only one color? (eg. Green)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design

Is there any way of converting a illustrator file with text and logos to one only. As I'm working for a client that only wants to print with one-color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **Illustrator CS4 or greater** it's pretty easy.

Select all the artwork.

Choose **Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork**

**#1**

---

If the **artwork contains black which you want to alter** as well.....
Click the little pref icon next to the "Preset" drop down menu. This will bring up the Color Reduction Options dialog.

- choose 1 from the colors drop down
- uncheck the "Black" item under "preserve"
- if "Grays" is checked, you'll want to uncheck that as well.

[image: with black]

Then Proceed to #3 below.

**2**

---

If the artwork does **NOT** contain any black, simply choose 1 under the color drop down in the middle of the dialog window. Then proceed to #3 below.

[image: recolor]

**#3**

---

Then double-click the little box under where it reads "New"

[image: New]

The Color picker will pop up... choose the color you want (you can use the basic color dialog or you can pick a swatch if you have a Pantone Swatch you want to use. Add the Pantone Color to the swatches before you start all this though.)  Then hit Okay.

Comment: Will this work with Bitmap images from Photoshop?

Comment: No. One color bitmap images will need to be individually clicked and then a color chosen. Multi color raster images placed in Illustrator will need to be edited in a raster editing application such as Photoshop.

Comment: how do you convert a bitmap image to one color in Photoshop?

Comment: @Josh if you have a question, you should post it as a question. Image > Mode > Greyscale creates 1 color images in Photoshop. If you need spot colors, the processes is more involved.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say "print"...

The general rule I've found among providers who print single color (single plate, single silk screen, whatever) is that they prefer the artwork itself in black with a specification as to the desired color (usually a Pantone number).

There may be exceptions to this, but I've not run across any. You or your client should ask the print provider for guidance on how they prefer the work set up.

You can very quickly convert to "black plate only" in Acrobat, of course, but Scott's approach will work nicely inside AI.

Comment: Makes it difficult to preview though. I've never had any issues working with spot colours in Illustrator and giving that to the printer. And if you import to Indesign the spots used will be appended to the ID palette. In PDF output, the objects will be described as a % of the spot colour.

Comment: That is true, but very often providers ask for black specifically or express it as a preference, especially for screen printing.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson How do you convert to "Black Plate Only?

Comment: In Acrobat, open the dialog `Tools > Print Production > Convert Colors` there is a checkbox under "Output Intent" labeled "Convert Colors to Output Intent." Choosing the appropriate Dot Gain profile will create a PDF with a black plate only.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson It shows Dot Gain Profile 10%, 20%, 30%. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The shop's been kinda busy... The dot gain you pick generally depends on how the piece will be printed, but that really only applies to screens (the "dots" in "dot gain"), not to 100% coverage. In this particular case it doesn't make a difference; the provider will simply use 100% coverage of whatever the actual print color is.

Answer (score 0):

This is supplementary info, but there's a bit you have to know about printing before you convert the artwork.

It sounds like you want your printers print a one colour job, i.e. use a single, pre-mixed green "spot colour" ink, rather than printing green tones with the normal CMYK process (cyan, magenta, yellow, black).

You need to specify exactly what green you want the printers to use. The normal way of doing this in most of the world is to choose a colour from the Pantone colour matching system. Can the client tell you the Pantone reference they normally use for this green? If they have a style guide, it should be in there.

If you need to pick the colour, all Adobe software will allow you to choose Pantone colours from a palette, but given you are dealing with ink, the reliable way of doing this is taking a look at a printed Pantone sample book. These are expensive, so unless you need to do this a lot, you'll probably want to borrow one, take a look at one when you meet your print rep etc.

(Just checking, there wasn't already a "what is a Pantone colour" question. So I've used this as the basis of one: [What is a spot/Pantone colour?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/what-is-a-spot-pantone-colour)).