# Create a two color printing image with only one color (dithering)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cmyk, flexography

In Illustrator: How do you create the color Grey with just using Black, but without changing opacity? (it can also be used for other colors)
[image: Example]
Whenever we have to print something (shopping bags, wrapping paper, etc) we have to create a template for each color that is used. There is a "cheat" where you take a graphic element and fill it with tiny dots in stead of a 100% solid fill, thus creating the illusion that a second "lighter" color is used. The "further" the dots are from each other, the "lighter" the color will be. But since its the same base color, it saves on having to create another template.

I hope that made sense.
[image]

**--> [Original file used by the producer in .pdf format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Bj4yemieaRWXgzX1Nlbm1peVU/edit?usp=sharing)** (open in Illustrator)

Comment: FYI: the term for what you are asking about is `dithering`. The images you link are `stochastic screening`.

Comment: @Matt_2.1 Here is an image which uses this technique. (the red circle bit). Only black was used for this shopping bag. http://i.imgur.com/MgMHDny.jpg

Comment: so to clarify the question: you are in need of a method or workflow where you provide plate-ready files for multiple inks where all overprinting and knockout (etc.) is already accounted for? Or do you just need to supply art for a single ink only (1 paper, 1 ink)?

Comment: @horatio A plate ready file yes. And for one single ink (but with the illusion of using two in stead of one). It saves on plate costs for the customer.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/how-to-convert-document-illustrator-file-to-only-one-color-eg-green

Comment: You should in any case contact the printer for advice on how to best setup a halftone. I hear that flexography processes can vary pretty drastically – it goes from crude to near-offset quality.

Comment: Customarily if you output something set at a tint of a color (less than 100%) the imagesetter/platemaker will generate the halftone dot necessary to reflect the screened value. I do not understand your question, and do not understand why you need to generate these screens yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just set your black to grey scale Black K and then adjust the black to the grey color you would like. Just a thought.

You currently have your pantone as black U 85% 
[image]

change it to grey scale
[image]

Side by side comparison:
[image]

Now your using the color black at 70%

Maybe I'm not understanding 100% what you are trying to achieve.